# What is the difference between L2TP vs GRE

Tags: gre, l2tp

Can anyone clearly explain that what is the difference between L2TP and GRE tunnel?
Is L2TPv3 Any different

I am  trying to understand where these protocol are used and why we use L2TP instead of GRE in some cases and vice versa.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

L2tp and GRE are totally diffrent protocols

GRE is a simple IP packet encapsulation protocol. a GRE tunnel is used when packets need to be sent from one network to another, without being parsed or treated like IP packets by any intervening routers. a GRE tunnel interface comes up as soon as it is configured and it stays up as long as there is a valid tunnel source address or interface which is up.

L2TP is a tunneling protocol (used to support VPNs) that allows multiplexing of multiple PPP sessions between two IP-connected endpoints, and a control protocol for dynamically establishing and maintaining the emulation of these PPP sessions. This is very different than GRE.

Comment: Please give credit where credit is due. This answer is just a C/P from [here](https://community.cisco.com/t5/routing/l2tp-vs-gre/m-p/1981308/highlight/true#M194939) (even with "a GRE tunnel ..." instead of capital "A").

Answer (score 0):

**L2tp** is primarily for vpn it is a combination of
pptp and cisco's l2f or layer 2 forwarding.

**GRE** is cisco's generic route epcapsulation
basically creating an ip tunnel to carry "other"
traffic accross an ip backbone. it must be terminated on the outside or closet points of the tunnel.